# i want to get one result from thre different list

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have function receive List : `list<json>`

inside this list many list:

```
list1<go> 
list2<come> 
list3<leave>
```

Code:

```
fun handleResults(it: json) {  
    var storeCoupons = when(id_choice.toInt()){
        0->it.list1
        1->it.list2
        else->it.list3
    }  

    while (i in i.. storeCoupons?.size!!-1){

        var pos=storeCoupons.get(i).title
        var img = storeCoupons?.get(i)?.image
        var id=storeCoupons?.get(i)?.id
        users.add(User(id.toString()!!,pos!!, img!!))

        i++
    }
}
```

the problem is the variable storeCoupons his data type is changed because its receive some types data type as list1 and another time list2 i guess should i make another list and add all the list inside it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're saying that `list1` and `list2` are different types, but..you want to use the same methods on both of them. Sounds like you need to define a base class that holds `title`, `image`, etc, and then have both lists extend from that. Then you can use them *generically*.

Here's an example of how to do that in Kotlin: https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/inheritance